# Java: Removing elements from an ArrayList and adding text

Tags: java, graphics, event-handling, arraylist

I'm having trouble with a Graph drawing program that stores elements (drawn rectangles and ellipses) in an ArrayList. I would like to remove specific rectangles and ellipses from the list by first selecting the element with the left mouse button and then deleting it using the right mouse button. However, the problem is that my program will delete a rectangle or ellipse without it having been selected by the left mouse button first (i.e., I can right click on any node and it will delete before it is selected).

I have declared an ArrayList of GraphElements as

```
ArrayList <GraphElement> element = new ArrayList<GraphElement>();
```

Inside the MousePressListener, the part I am having difficulty with is (the setLabel part of the code is related to my next question):

```
for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++)
  {
  GraphElement el =  (GraphElement)element.get(i);
        el.isSelected(x, y); // isSelected method (functioning correctly) to check whether the coordinates are inside the bounds of the rectangle or ellipse
        if (el.isSelected(x,y))
        {                   
          if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) // delete a node
             element.remove(i).isSelected(x, y);
          if (setLabel)
         {
           el.setLabel(label);
           setLabel = false;
           repaint();
         }  
         }
}
```

Secondly, I would like to add a label to the selected rectangle or ellipse. This is done in my program by selecting the rectangle or ellipse to add text, entering text into a JTextField and then selecting the JButton to apply the changes. However, my problem is that the label is not drawn on the component after I press the JButton. I must press the mouse button again for the text to show. I guess it is because I have the setLabel in my MousePressListener. But I need to select the element before adding text, so I don't know how to go about this.

Here is the ActionListener for the labels:

```
  class addLabel implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        component.setLabel(labelField.getText());
    }
  }
  addLabel label = new addLabel();
  labelButton.addActionListener(label);
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You should use Iterator.remove() method to delete items from your ArrayList. Read about [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html).

Comment: Or iterate backwards through the ArrayList. This actually makes sense if you draw the items by iterating forwards, since you want the click to activate the top-most item.

Comment: @Max - this is not the OP's real problem, and since the collection is an ArrayList, it is going to make little difference performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

This statement looks highly suspect:

```
element.remove(i).isSelected(x, y);
```

It seems to say

> "remove the ith element from the list, AND THEN test to see if `x, y` is within it"

You want to test if the ith element is selected BEFORE you remove it.